# VIM can't be used after system upgrade to ubuntu18.04

Tags: vim, ubuntu-18.04

I upgraded my system from ubuntu16.04 to ubuntu18.04,once I updated my system，I fond that my VIM could not be used.Whenever I use my VIM,the following mistakes will occur.

> $ vim test.cpp
>
> vim: error while loading shared libraries: libruby-2.3.so.2.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

What should I do?
Help me slove this problem,thanks!

Comment: Your Vim used to be linked against a certain Ruby version, but now that version is uninstalled and presumably a newer version is installed instead by the version upgrade. Reinstall Vim to link with the current Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If this is the default Vim installed via your package manager, that's not supposed to happen. Something's messed up, and I would attempt a complete purge and reinstall of the Vim packages.
- If you've compiled Vim yourself (then it's typically installed as `/usr/local/bin/vim`, or under your home directory), **you need to recompile it**.

Vim typically isn't a static, standalone binary. Especially for the language interpreters (Perl, Python, Ruby), it links to them via *shared libraries*. You'll see some of this in the `:version` output.

On the positive side, this means that any fixes and enhancements automatically get into Vim as well. On the negative side, this means that if one of those dependent libraries get upgraded (as happens during a system upgrade) and the old version is lost, you have to recompile Vim, so that the new dependencies are incorporated into it. The also implies that it's not advisable to copy a self-compiled Vim to another Linux system (unless you're sure it's on the exactly same version), and compile on each system instead.

Comment: The proble has benn solved.I use this command to completely delete VIM
“whereis vim | xargs rm -rf“

then reinstall it，then it can be used.
Thank you!

Comment: Ah, okay. A bit of a crude solution (especially since `whereis` may find both default and self-compiled Vim executables), but as long as it solved the problem, who's to argue?

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark. This way, the question is marked as closed, and you increase your chances of getting answers to future questions, as this shows that you care about the answers.

Comment: I thought about it for a while,I learned about VIM configuration on GitHub before.Then I went
to check the source code,I fond that the script did recomplie and install VIM,I think the
question should be here.So I thing I should try again to solve this problem.